# Iterating over DictReader variable

Tags: python

Ok so the contents of a csv file is the below, when using DictReader

```
{'name': 'Alice', 'AGATC': '2', 'AATG': '8', 'TATC': '3'}
{'name': 'Bob', 'AGATC': '4', 'AATG': '1', 'TATC': '5'}
{'name': 'Charlie', 'AGATC': '3', 'AATG': '2', 'TATC': '5'}

with open(sys.argv[1], "r") as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
    
    names = []

    for row in csv_reader:
        names.append(row["name"])
    print(names)

    agatc = []

    for row in csv_reader:
        agatc.append(row["AGATC"])
    print(agatc)
```

The output I get

```
['Alice', 'Bob', 'Charlie']
[]
```

confuses me since the agatc-list is empty. What am I missing here, surely it's possible to iterate over the contents of what DictReader returns more than once?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: "surely it's possible to iterate over the contents of what DictReader returns more than once?" No, actually: iterators (unlike sequences) can only be iterated over once. You will need to keep a copy of the rows in the first iteration.

Comment: Thanks so much @slhck, lots to learn, but having fun on the journey! All the best